# in_array php function return false

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the result from the database and compare it to the current value

```
$pagetitle = DB::table('page')->select('title')->get();
```

And I am getting the result like this:

```
array:72 [▼
  0 => {#593 ▼
    +"title": "About"
  }
  1 => {#592 ▼
    +"title": "Home"
  }
  2 => {#591 ▼
    +"title": "Contact"
  }
  3 => {#567 ▼
    +"title": "Portfolio"
  }
  4 => {#568 ▼
    +"title": "Settings"
  }
```

But when I try to find if the value exists in array I always get false.

```
dd(in_array('About', $pagetitle));
```

Can anybody clear this out for me?

Comment: Because there's no `About` value in your array.

Comment: What is "About"? How can I access it?

Comment: I think you would be using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) like `$key = array_search('About', array_column($pagetitle, 'title'));`

Comment: @bansi isn't `$pageTitle` supposed to give object, or is it not?

Comment: @bansi it worked! Thanks!